# kubectl list / delete all completed jobs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

I'm looking for a **kubectl** command to list / delete **all** completed **jobs**

I've try:

```
kubectl get job --field-selector status.succeeded=1
```

But I get:

```
enfield selector "status.succeeded=1": field label "status.succeeded" not supported for batchv1.Jobter code here
```

What are the possible fields for **--fieldSelector** when getting jobs ?

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: if you have a common label attached to the pod you can use #kubectl delete job -l app=myjob

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you can do to list all the succeeded jobs is first get all the jobs and then filter the output:

```
kubectl get job --all-namespaces | grep "succeeded"
```

If you want to delete all the succeded jobs you can use the following command:

```
kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}')
```

Comment: The first command does not work. We might have different kubectl version.
The second command work great ! Thanks !

Comment: The first command does not work as @should_be_working pointed out. That's because there is no field that describes the status of a job as "succeeded" in the default `kubectl get job` list.

Comment: If working with powershell, the command to list all the succeeded jobs is: `kubectl get job --all-namespaces | select-string "succeeded"`

Comment: I think it's beneficial to stress that in this answer the filtering is obtained by the Filtering expression `[?(expression)]`. At first, it was not obvious to me how an output template could act as a filter. In filter expressions the `@` is the current node being processed. More on Filter Expression here: https://rows.com/docs/filtering-with-jsonpath#filtering

Answer (score 38):

you are almost there, you can do below to delete completed jobs

```
kubectl delete jobs --all-namespaces --field-selector status.successful=1
```

Comment: great, do you have docs why this works? I only found "Supported field selectors vary by Kubernetes resource type" in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/ and given that jobs have `status.succeeded: 1` in their yaml it is not very intuitive (although it works).

Comment: Little bit late, but I eventually managed to track down where these are defined https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#job-v1-batch

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, the following returns all jobs that have failed:

```
kubectl get jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.failed>0)].metadata.name}')
```

And all jobs that are still running:

```
kubectl get jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.active==1)].metadata.name}')
```

Answer (score 4):

More elegant and shorter version:

```
kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded
```