# How can I find the list of field selectors supported by kubectl for a given resource type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've recently learned about kubectl `--field-selector` flag, but ran into errors when trying to use it with various objects.

For example :

```sh
$ kubectl delete jobs.batch --field-selector status.succeeded==1
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "batch/v1, Resource=jobs" that match label selector "", field selector "status.succeeded==1": field label "status.succeeded" not supported for batchv1.Job
```

According to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields), `Supported field selectors vary by Kubernetes resource type.`, so I guess this behaviour was to be expected.

The annoying part is that I had to try individually each field to know if I could use them or not.

Is there any way to get all the fields supported for a given resource type / resource version / kubectl version ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue in your case is that you mistakenly use `status.succeeded` instead of `status.successful`, so right command is

```
kubectl delete jobs.batch --field-selector status.successful==1
No resources found
```

Regarding your question about all the fields: my suggestion is to deep into the code and search for proper resources types in conversion.go for each API.

Example:
[Batch Jobs conversion.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/batch/v1/conversion.go#L30-L41)

```
    return scheme.AddFieldLabelConversionFunc(SchemeGroupVersion.WithKind("Job"),
        func(label, value string) (string, string, error) {
            switch label {
            case "metadata.name", "metadata.namespace", "status.successful":
                return label, value, nil
            default:
                return "", "", fmt.Errorf("field label %q not supported for batchv1.Job", label)
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: A successful job returns `"succeeded":1` in the status json, so is it a bug that the field selector doesn't match the name of the field?

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. Is there any way to get all the fields supported for a given resource type / resource version / kubectl version ?

Comment: You are a hero! Though cryptic my quest for a list of supported fields for the label selector has finally yielded some results

Comment: Just realized answer is old and url should be updated. done

Comment: filters for apps v1 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/691d4c3989f18e0be22c4499d22eff95d516d32b/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L38

Answer (score 5):

For the record, although that doesn't answer the question, it's possible to work around this limitation with `jsonPath`.

For instance, the example above can be done like this :

```
kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}')
```

(solution inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540996/5771067)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to list resources (e.g. of type "Machine") in all namespaces, with **status phase not running**:

```
kubectl get Machine -A -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase!="Running")].metadata.name}'
```

To **print the error message** of those failed resources:

```
kubectl get Machine -A -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Failed")].status.errorMessage}'
```

Output example:

> nmanos-cluster-a-v5jcx-submariner-gw-us-west-1b-pwwrk: reconciler
> failed to Create machine: failed to launch instance: error launching
> instance: The requested configuration is currently not supported.
> Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

Comment: In case someone want to use it in an shell if-statement (example with tekton pipelinerun ressource, same behaviour with any other ressource depending on json): 
 `if [ $(kubectl get pipelinerun --selector='notification-provider' -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.conditions[*].reason=="Running")].metadata.name}' | wc -c) -gt 0 ]; then echo Found running pipelines!; fi`