# Deleting failed jobs in kubernetes (gke)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

How to delete the failed jobs in the kubernetes cluster using a cron job in gke?. when i tried to delete the failed jobs using following YAML, it has deleted all the jobs (including running)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
name: XXX
namespace: XXX
spec:
schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
jobTemplate:
 spec:
   template:
     spec:
       serviceAccountName: XXX
       containers:
       - name: kubectl-runner
         image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
         command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl delete jobs $(kubectl get jobs | awk '$2 ~ 1/1' | awk '{print $1}')"]
       restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: How this job getting triggered? if cron then you can set .spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit. and If this are normal one can't you just check COMPLETIONS field

Comment: I agree what was said by user yogesh kunjir. You should be able to set a limit for your failed jobs in the CronJob. You can also look on this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539576/kubectl-list-delete-all-completed-jobs . You will need to modify it it support "Failed" Jobs.

Comment: @yogeshkunjir actually the above yaml is a cron-job, which is trying to delete failed normal jobs. And i have already tried the following , but it's not deleting the jobs. kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.Failed==1)].metadata.name}')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one visually looks better for me:

```
kubectl delete job --field-selector=status.phase==Failed
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete failed **`Jobs`** in `GKE` you will need to use following command:

- `$ kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.failed==1)].metadata.name}')`

This command will output the `JSON` for all jobs and search for jobs that have `status.failed` field set to `1`. It will then pass the failed jobs to `$ kubectl delete jobs`

---

**This command ran in a `CronJob`  will fail when there are no jobs with status: `failed`.**

As a **workaround** you can use:

```yaml
command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl delete job --ignore-not-found=true $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.failed==1)].metadata.name}'); exit 0"]
```

> `exit 0` was added to make sure that the `Pod` will leave with status code 0

---

As for part of the comments made under the question:

> You will need to modify it it support **"Failed"** Jobs

> I have already tried the following , but it's not deleting the jobs. `kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.Failed==1)].metadata.name}')`

- `@.status.Failed==1` <-- incorrect as `JSON` is [case sensitive](https://www.quora.com/Is-JSON-case-sensitive)
- `@.status.failed==1` <-- correct

If you were to run incorrect version of this command on following Pods (to show that they failed and aren't still running to completion):

```
NAME              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
job-four-9w5h9    0/1     Error       0          5s
job-one-n9trm     0/1     Completed   0          6s
job-three-nhqb6   0/1     Error       0          5s
job-two-hkz8r     0/1     Error       0          6s
```

You should get the following error :

```
error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified
```

> Above error will also  show when there was no jobs passed to `$ kubectl delete job`.

Running correct version of this command should delete all jobs that failed:

```
job.batch "job-four" deleted
job.batch "job-three" deleted
job.batch "job-two" deleted
```

---

I encourage you to check additional resources:

- *[StackOverflow.com: Questions: Kubectl list delete all completed jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539576/kubectl-list-delete-all-completed-jobs)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)*

Comment: If a job has failed twice and had succeeded the third time and if you have kept the `failedJobsHistoryLimit` to 2, then in the command you will need to set `status.failed==2` instead of `status.failed==1`

Answer (score 1):

@Dawid Kruk answer is excellent but working on a specific namespace only and not for all namespaces as I needed.
in order to solve it, I've created a simple bash script that gets all failed jobs and delete them -

```bash
# Delete failed jobs
failedJobs=$(kubectl get job -A -o=jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.failed>=1)]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.metadata.namespace}{"\n"}{end}')
echo "$failedJobs" | while read each
do
  array=($each)
  jobName=${array[0]}
  namespace=${array[1]}
  echo "Debug: job name: $jobName is deleted on namespace $namespace"
  kubectl delete job  $jobName -n $namespace
done
```